# How do I detect and delete abbreviations with regex in R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a column with the following kind of strings:

```
Author 

Achebe, Chinua.  Ach
Akbar, M.j.  Akb
Alanahally, Srikrishna.  Ala
```

These are names of authors with their shortened abbreviation at the end. This is only at the end, because if I just look for three letter words, author names like Jon and Sam will be deleted. This usually occurs after two spaces. I want to eliminate this. I wrote the following regex to detect and delete these:

```
data$Author <- gsub("\\s([A-Z]+[A-Za-z]{2})\\s", "", data$Author)
```

What do I change in this so that I can delete these three letter abbreviations?

Comment: Do every author have 3 letter abbreviation of their name at the end? Can you just remove last 3 letters from each string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\\s` at the end of the pattern is forcing a space after the three-letters, and none of the samples have that here. Options:

1. You cannot remove it or replace it with `\\s*`, as those will be too permissive (and break things):

   ```r
   gsub("\\s([A-Z]+[A-Za-z]{2})", "", authors)
   # [1] "Achebe,nua. "         "Akbar, M.j. "         "Alanahally,krishna. "
   ```
2. add a word-boundary `\\b`

   ```r
   gsub("\\s([A-Z]+[A-Za-z]{2})\\b", "", authors)
   # [1] "Achebe, Chinua. "         "Akbar, M.j. "             "Alanahally, Srikrishna. "
   ```
3. change to end-of-string

   ```r
   gsub("\\s([A-Z]+[A-Za-z]{2})$", "", authors)
   # [1] "Achebe, Chinua. "         "Akbar, M.j. "             "Alanahally, Srikrishna. "
   ```

   (though I think this might be over-constraining).

---

Data

```r
authors <- c("Achebe, Chinua.  Ach", "Akbar, M.j.  Akb", "Alanahally, Srikrishna.  Ala")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty comprehensive. Is there any way to add exclusions within this regex? I just looked through and it is removing authors such as `Fry, Ben`. Can I exclude words like Ben, Sam and Jon?

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, and while it might be possible (I don't know how off the top of my head), I think a better case couple be made for `gsub`ing a subset of `authors`, perhaps `fryben <- grepl("\b(Fry|Ben)\b", authors)`, and then `gsub(..., authors[!fryben])`, or something like that. (It's also a lot easier to see, to add exclusions/filters, and therefore to maintain.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with  (find & replace) syntax ,

Find:  `\s?\s\w+$`

Replace:  `leave it empty`